# ScrollView with OnTouch event

Tags: java, android

I have a `ScrollView` and a very long text on `TextView` and I want to drag to the next/previous text according to the user action like that:

On my xml:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewTest"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">            
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="very long text" />    
</ScrollView>
```

On the onCreate I implemented the `OnTouchListener` in order to drag to the next text.

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewTest);         
sv.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouch());
```

The `OnTouchListener` define like that:

```
public class MyOnTouch implements OnTouchListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return pageFlip(v, event);           
   }

   public boolean pageFlip(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           startX = event.getX();
           break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           float currentX = event.getX();       
            if (startX > currentX + 150 ) {
                nextText(v);
            }
            if (startX  < currentX - 150) {                
                previousText(v);
            }
       default:
           break;
   }
   return true;
   }
}
```

The problem is when I'm implement it like that I can get to the next/previous text but I can't scroll up and down in order to see the text in the bottom.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In method `pageFlip` change `return true;` to `return false;`

Comment: @choop, so now you can continue to develop, awesome! :)